# Get BigQuery table schema using google.cloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I can for example get BigQuery data into local python with:

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

project_id = "example-project"
dataset_id = "exapmle_dataset"
table_id = "table_id"

os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = project_id
bq = bigquery.Client()

query = "SELECT * FROM {}.{} LIMIT 5".format(dataset_id, table_id)
resp = bq.run_sync_query(query)
resp.run()
data_list = resp.rows
```

The result:

```
print(data_list)
>>> [('BEDD', '1',), ('A75', '1',), ('CE3F', '1',), ('0D8C', '1',), ('3E9C', '1',)]
```

How do I then go and get the schema for this table?  Such that, for example

```
headings = ('heading1', 'heading2')
# or
schema_dict = {'fields': [{'name': 'heading1', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'heading2', 'type': 'STRING'}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `schema` method from your `resp` variable.

After running the query you can retrieve it:

```
schema = resp.schema
```

**schema** will be a list containing the definition for each column in your query.

As an example, lets say this is your query:

```
query = "select '1' as fv, STRUCT<i INT64, j INT64> (1, 2) t  from `dataset.table` limit 1"
```

The schema will be a list containing 2 entries:

```
[<google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField at 0x7ffa64fe6e50>,
 <google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField at 0x7ffa64fe6b10>]
```

For each object in schema, you have the methods `field_type`, `fields`, `mode` and `name` so if you run:

```
schema[0].field_type, schema[0].mode, schema[0].name
```

The result is "STRING", "NULLABLE", "fv".

As the second column is a record, then if you run:

```
schema[1].field_type, schema[1].mode, schema[1].name, schema[1].fields
```

The result is:

"RECORD", "NULLABLE", "t", [google schema 1, google schema 2]

Where `google schema 1` contains the definition for the inner fields within the record.

As far as I know, there's no way of getting a dictionary as you showed in your question, which means you'll have to loop over the entries in `schema` and build it yourself. It should be simple though. Not sure if this is working as I haven't fully tested it but it might give you an idea on how to do it:

```
def extract_schema(schema_resp):
    l = []
    for schema_obj in schema_resp:
        r = {}
        r['name'] = schema_obj.name
        r['type'] = schema_obj.field_type
        r['mode'] = schema_obj.mode
        if schema_obj.fields:
            r['fields'] = extract_schema(schema_obj.fields)
        l.append(r)
    return l
```

So you'd just have to run `schema = extract_schema(resp.schema)` and (hopefully) you'll be good to go.